# Circular contour map in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, contour

I have a 120mm diameter circular disk, where I measure temperature at 20 different locations. These measurement locations are at random places. I am looking for a way to plot it as in attached desired plot link. When I used tricontour, It just plots the random points. I am unable to find a way to fill the circle as in below attached pic. Is there any other way to plot this? Spent lot of time searching for it with no success.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {"x": [110,50,-85,20,45,0,-80,-30,-105,80], "y": 
[0,100,75,-90,20,115,-85,-20,-45,-90],"z":[10,2,6,4,9,12,2,6,4,12]}
x = data['x']
y = data['y']
z = data['z']

f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
plot = ax.tricontourf(x,y,z, 20) 
ax.plot(x,y, 'ko ')
circ1 = Circle((0, 0), 120, facecolor='None', edgecolor='r', lw=5)
ax.add_patch(circ1)
f.colorbar(plot)
```

Example data :

[image]

Desired plot:
[image]

What I got from tricontour:

[image]

Comment: Matplotlib has polar axes

Answer (score 0):

There is much data to do a really nice coontour plot, but here is a solution with your data and an example with a substantially larger dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri


data = {"x": [110,50,-85,20,45,0,-80,-30,-105,80], "y": 
[0,100,75,-90,20,115,-85,-20,-45,-90],"z":[10,2,6,4,9,12,2,6,4,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')

ax.set_title("tricontour")
ax.tricontourf(df["x"], df["y"], df["z"],20)

plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

and for a larger dataframe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(1000, 3)), columns=list('XYZ'))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')

ax.set_title("tricontour")
ax.tricontourf(df["X"], df["Y"], df["Z"],20)

plt.show()
```

which returns

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My intention is to fill the entire circle of 120mm diameter with available data points. Either by extrapolating it or some other way.